# Reload content in div with switch case include

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am kinda new in Ajax and jQuery the problem is that I have a folder pages and in it are php pages with content divs. I want to reload the container div with the content instead of the whole page i tried many things but nothing seems to help. this is a part of how my index.php looks like:

```
<?php include ('inc/nav.php'); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <?
            $type = $_GET["type"];
            switch ($type) {
                case "about" :
                    include "pages/about-us.php";
                    break;
                case "contact":
                    include "pages/contact.php";
                    break;
                default :
                    include "pages/homepage.php";
            }
            ?>
          </div>
```

In the navigation the link looks like this:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=homepage">Homepage</a></li>
    <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=about-us">About us</a></li>
    <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to get the content that's in pages/about-us.php into the `<div id="container"></div>` but it's not working. this is how my ajax script looks like:

```
//run on page load
$(function(){
    //bind a click event to the nav links
    $(".url a").on("click", function(e){

        //keep the links from going to another page by preventing their default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //this = link; grab the url
        var pageLocation = this.href;
        console.log(pageLocation);
        //fire off an ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: pageLocation,

            //on success, set the html to the responsetext
            success: function(data){
                $("#container").html(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: your going to loose any attached js events on pulled in dom, but to answer do `$("#container").html($(data.responseText).find('#container'));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *As of jQuery 3.0, `.bind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.* Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It wouold also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i updated the code with your answer but when i load the page it gets empty

Comment: @Twisty i have updated my code and provided a minimal code

Comment: @5admin do you see any Errors in your Console? What does the Request and Response look like?

Comment: @5admin I do not see in your HTML where `$("#container")` exists. If you're calling the page that contains `$("#container")`, then this is why the code is failing.

Comment: Might also consider using https://api.jquery.com/load/ instead.

Comment: The div in index.php does contain the id container. i have checked the error logs but nothing seems to show.

Answer (score 0):

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".url a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageLocation = this.href + " #container";
    console.log(pageLocation);
    $("#container").load(pageLocation)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=homepage">Homepage</a></li>
  <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=about-us">About us</a></li>
  <li class="url"><a href="index.php?type=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

This is untested. You will want to test this in your own code.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: it worked! but later on if im going to post forms etc this wont be a problem?

Comment: @5admin posting forms is completely different than clicking links, so I doubt it will be the same code.

Comment: Okay, but now i have the issue that when i click on the link the url disappears and only become domain.com/

Comment: @5admin keep checking. You can mark this as the answer and if you can't find an answer to your new issue, post it.